# Error 1064 you have error in Mysql bench syntax

Tags: sql, database, mysql-workbench

Last two line show error .MY sqlwork bench show syntax error in last two line Limit 1 
End
trying to run Database procedures.Error code Error 1064 you have error in Mysql bench syntax

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `xyz_Get`(

        IN pPlaceId BIGINT,
        IN pSwitchedCompanyId BIGINT,
        IN pRequestedBy BIGINT
    )
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            `PlaceId`,
            `CategoryCode`,
            `CategoryName`,
            `Description`,
            `ParentCategoryId_FK`,
            `ModuleId_FK`,
            `LanguageId_FK`,
            `CompanyId_FK`,
            `OwnerCompanyId_FK`,
            `IsDeleted`,
            `IsArchived`,
            `CreatedDate`,
            `ModifiedDate`,
            `CreatedBy_FK`,
            `ModifiedBy_FK`
        FROM `xyz_Place`
        WHERE
            `PlaceId` = pPlaceId AND
            (
                `CompanyId_FK` = pSwitchedCompanyId OR
                `OwnerCompanyId_FK` = pSwitchedCompanyId
            )
            AND `IsDeleted` = 0
        LIMIT 1;
    END
```

Comment: You probably just need to set the `DELIMITER`s.

Comment: Yes you are Right Thanks @GordonLinoff